# symplectic structure of tangent bundle of $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, cotangent-bundles

It is  well known that   $T\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ is diffeomorphic to $M= f^{-1}(1)$ where 
$f:\mathbb{C}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is $f(z):=\sum_{i=1}^{n} z_{i}^{2}$.
Two questions:

1) Is  $M$  a  symplectic  submanifold of $\mathbb{C}^n\sim \mathbb{R}^{2n}$ (with the standard symplectic structure)?

If  the answer is affirmative, we can consider two  symplectic structures for $T\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$. The first is the original structure of the tangent or  cotangent bundle, the second one is the  pull back  structure of  $M$.

2) Are these structures equivalent?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a formula for an explicit symplectomorphism $F$ from $T^*S^{n-1}$ to the affine quadric $\{\sum z_{j}^{2}=1\}$ in $\mathbb{C}^n$:

$$ 
F(p,q) = \left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4|p|^2}}{2}\right)^{1/2} q - i\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4|p|^2}}{2}\right)^{-1/2}p 
$$

Here I view $T^*S^{n-1}$ as consisting of pairs $(p,q)\in \mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n$ with $p\cdot q=0$ and $|q|=1$.  To check that $F$ is a symplectomorphism one can just check that $F$ pulls back the one-form $\alpha=-\sum y_jdx_j$ on $\mathbb{C}^n$ (which is a primitive for the standard symplectic form) to the canonical one-form on $T^*S^{n-1}$.  The coefficients involving $\sqrt{1+4|p|^2}$ are designed to cause the map to have image in the quadric.

To indicate how I came up with this formula, the reasoning was that a suitably natural symplectomorphism ought to be equivariant with respect to the natural Hamiltonian $O(n)$-actions on both spaces.  The easiest way to do this seems to be to take $F(p,q)=f(|p|)q-ig(|p|)p$ for some real functions $f$ and $g$.  For the image to be in the quadric one needs $$f(|p|)^2- |p|^2g(|p|)^2=1.$$  Meanwhile if this is to be a symplectomorphism it should pull back the moment map for the $O(n)$-action on $\mathbb{C}^n$ to the moment map for the $O(n)$-action on $T^*S^{n-1}$.  The norms of these moment maps are, respectively $(x+iy)\mapsto |x||y|$ and $(p,q)\mapsto |p|$, giving an equation $|f||g||p|=|p|$, i.e., $$|g|=\frac{1}{|f|}.$$ Solving these for $f$ and $g$ yields the formula at the top, which can then be directly confirmed to have the required properties.

Comment: I didn't check your computation, but that's not the point. I just want to congratulate you for using the wording "Moment Map" :-})

Comment: Mike thank you for your beutiful answer. But do you mean that an arbitrary symplectomorphism is necessarily equivariant with respect to O(n) action?

Comment: No, that certainly wouldn't be the case (for instance if you composed the symplectomorphism in the answer with a non-equivariant symplectomorphism of the domain--of which there are many--the result wouldn't be equivariant).  The idea of asking for O(n)-equivariance was just to narrow down the search, and also to take advantage of the fact that an equivariant symplectomorphism will respect the moment maps (thus giving a function that the map should preserve, which is usually easier to arrange than preserving a form).

Answer (score 7):

$
\def\C{{\mathbf C}}
\def\d{\delta}
\def\e{{\mathbf e}}
\def\r{{\mathbf r}}
\def\u{{\mathbf u}}
\def\x{{\mathbf x}}
\def\y{{\mathbf y}}
\def\z{{\mathbf z}}
\def\<{\langle}
\def\>{\rangle}
$
<del>If I understand</del> Now that I understand your questions correctly, the answers are 1) Yes 2) <del>No</del> Yes.

1) Writing $\z=\x+i\y$, we have $f(\z) = \|\x\|^2 - \|\y\|^2+2i\<\x,\y\>$. So $M=f^{-1}(1)$ (resp. $\mathrm T_\z M$) consists of all $\z$ (resp. $\d\z=\d\x+i\d\y$) such that
$$
\|\x\|^2 - \|\y\|^2= 1, \qquad \<\x,\y\>=0,
\tag1
$$
$$
\llap{(\text{resp.}\qquad}\<\x,\d\x\>-\<\y,\d\y\>=0,\qquad\<\d\x,\y\>+\<\x,\d\y\>=0.)
\tag2
$$
Given $\z$ in (1), we can choose an orthonormal basis $(\e_1,\dots,\e_n)$ such that $\x = \|\x\|\e_1$ and $\mathbf y = \|\y\|\e_2$. Then (2) says that $(\d x_1,\d y_1)=\frac{\|\y\|}{\|\x\|}(\d y_2,-\d x_2)$ and hence
\begin{align}
\omega(\d\z,\d'\z)
&=
\sum_{i=1}^n(\d x_i\d'y_i-\d'x_i\d y_i)\\
&=\Bigl(1+\tfrac{\|\y\|^2}{\|\x\|^2}\Bigr)(\d x_2\d'y_2-\d'x_2\d y_2)
+ \sum_{i=3}^n(\d x_i\d'y_i-\d'x_i\d y_i)
\end{align}
which is obviously nondegenerate. (Or as Tim Perutz says, just note that $M$ is a complex submanifold.)

2) Consider (after Seidel's thesis pointed out by Daniel Pomerleano) the diffeo $\Phi:M\to\mathrm{TS}^{n-1}$ sending $\z=\x+i\y$ to the pair $(\u,\r)=(\frac{\x}{\|\x\|}, \|\x\|\y)$. Writing $\sigma$ for the canonical 2-form $d\<\u,d\r\>$ on $\mathrm{TS}^{n-1}$, we have
\begin{align}
\Phi^*\sigma &= d(\Phi^*\<\u,d\r\>)=d(\<\tfrac{\x}{\|\x\|},d(\|\x\|\y)\>)\\
&=d\<\x,d\y\> + \<\x,\y\>\tfrac{d\|\x\|}{\|\x\|}
\end{align}
and this equals $\omega$ since the second term vanishes by (1). Thus $\Phi$ is a symplectomorphism.

3) My initial (stupid and wrong) answer came from my thinking of another similar question. Namely $\mathrm{TS}^2$, thought of as the manifold of oriented affine lines in $\mathbf R^3$ (identify $(\u,\r)$ with the line $\r+\mathbf R\u$ with orientation $+\u$), carries a 2-parameter family of Euclid-invariant symplectic structures given by
$$
\omega_{k,s} = d\<k\u,d\r\> - s\Omega,\qquad k>0, s\in \mathbf R,
\tag3
$$
where the first term is the cotangent bundle 2-form, and the second ("magnetic") term is $-s$ times the area 2-form of the base $\mathrm S^2$.

On the other hand, identifying $\mathfrak{so}(3,\C)=\C^3$ with Lie bracket the vector product, the nonzero levels of your quadratic form $\<\z,\z\>=\sum_{i=1}^3 z_i^2$ are precisely the semisimple (co)adjoint orbits of $\mathrm{SO}(3,\C)$. As such they carry a (Kirillov-Kostant-Souriau) 2-form $\omega_{\mathrm{KKS}}(\d\z,\d'\z)=\mathrm{Re}\bigl(\frac1{s^2}\<\z,\d'\z\times\d\z\>\bigr)$ where $\<\z,\z\>=s^2$ is the equation of our orbit $\mathcal O$. So we can again ask if this is symplectomorphic with $\mathrm{TS}^2$ equipped with one of the forms (3). At least when $s^2$ is real positive, the answer is yes and the diffeomorphism $F:\mathrm{TS}^2\to\mathcal O$ I was considering (with $k=s=1$),
$$
F(\u,\r) = k\r\times\u + s\u + ik\r
$$
is symplectic: $F^*\omega_{\mathrm{KKS}}=\omega_{k,s}$. Being familiar with this diffeomorphism, I then made the mistake of thinking it must be "the one" of which you were asking if it was symplectic relative to your (different) 2-forms. And it isn't.

Comment: Not many people use $\delta$ to denote tangent vectors...

Comment: Only perverts like [us](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/146042/can-the-equation-of-motion-with-friction-be-written-as-euler-lagrange-equation/150154#150154)!

Comment: For 1), there's no need to compute: $M$ is a complex submanifold of $\mathbb{C}^n$, hence a symplectic submanifold.

Comment: I'm very confused: I think the answer to question 2 is "yes" if we mean "symplectomorphic". See e.g. Lemma 18.1 of Seidel's thesis or lemma 6.11 of http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0006056v2.pdf.

Comment: Yes in my question I mean symplectomorphism. but how lema 6.11 implies that they are sympletctomrphism?

Comment: Check the other paper, that should make things clear. Also, I'm sure it's in Seidel's book on Picard Lefschetz theory. The fact you want is only stated within the proof of 6.11.

Comment: Part 2 of the answer successfully shows that a certain specific diffeomorphism between the spaces is not a symplectomorphism...of course this is not the same as showing that they are not symplectomorphic.

Comment: @TimPerutz You're absolutely right :-)

Comment: @DanielPomerleano, Mike Usher: Thanks for setting me straight. I have now corrected my answer accordingly.

Comment: Tim,Daniel,Mike and Francois, thanks a lot for your helps

Comment: Thank you again for your interesting answer. I am sorry I am not able to accept two answers simultaneously. BTW I am browsing your thesis"Method des orbit et representation quantiques"