# Two questions related to $TS^{2}$ as a holomorphic manifold

Tags: complex-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, cv.complex-variables, differential-equations, vector-bundles

We consider $TS^{2}$ as  a  2  dimensional holomorphic manifold and fix  an explicit   holomorphic  structure on $TS^{2}$ as it is  indicated in the  answer of  Mike Usher to the [following  question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/150344/symplectic-structure-of-tangent-bundle-of-mathbbsn-1). We have two questions which are not  necessarily related to each others(directly).

> 1)Is there  a  **holomorphic**  map $q:TS^{2}\to S^{2}$ such that $(TS^{2}, S^{2}, q)$  has an  structure of  a holomorphic line  bundle or at least  topological one  dim. complex line  bundle or two  dim real  vector  bundle?
>
> 2) Consider the  natural  projection $p:TS^{2}\to S^{2}$. By  definition, a  holomorphic  vector  field on $S^{2}$ is  a  holomorphic  map $X:S^{2}\to TS^{2}$ with $p\circ X=Id.$ To what extend these holomorphic  vector  fields have  been classified? In  particular what  can  be  said about the nature of  singularities  and  closed orbits  of  a  holomorphic  vector  field? Can we  have  a  singularity  with negative index, ex: saddle point? Can  we  have  a  limit  cycle for  a  holomorphic  vector  field? Is the  space of  holomorphic  vector  field  a  Lie  algebra, that is  closed under the  usual Lie  bracket?

**Note 1:** In the  above  questions, $S^{2}$  is  identified with the  one  dim complex  manifold $\mathbb{C}P^{1}$

**Note 2:** The  second  question is  weakly  motivated  by the  following  facts: Let $F:U\to \mathbb{C}$ be  a  holomorphic  map  where $U\subset \mathbb{C}$ is  an  open subset. Then the  index of  each singular  point of the vector  field $\dot x=F(x)$ is non negative. Moreover such vector  fields have    no  limit  cycle, because $[F,iF]=0$ on the other hand every two  commuting  flows share on limit  cycles, that is  every  limit  cycles of one is  invariant under the other ones.  The other reason that $\dot x= F(x)$ has no limit cycle is that for each $t$ the flow $\phi_{t}$ is  a  holomorphic map Now put $T=\text{the period of  limit cycle}$. So $\phi_{T}$ as  a holomorphic  maps has  a curve of  fixed points. this  implies that $\phi_{T}$ is  identicaly equal to the identity map. So  a  closed orbit lies  in a band of  closed orbit with the same  period. so there is  no  an isolated closed orbit, i.e. limit cycle.

Comment: Careful: if we take the natural orientation on $TS^2$ induced from that of $S^2$, we get $TS^2=O(2)$. But with the opposite orientation we get $O(-2)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This discussion seems to involve two holomorphic structures on the smooth manifold $T S^2$.

**Structure 1** Identify $S^2$ with $\mathbb{CP}^1$. Place a complex structure on the real tangent bundle to $\mathbb{CP}^1$ by using the complex structure on $\mathbb{CP}^1$. This is the structure Alex Degtyarev's answer refers to. As Alex says, this is the line bundle $\mathcal{O}(2)$ and has a three dimensional vector space of holomorphic sections. If we write $z$ for a coordinate on $\mathbb{CP}^1$, they are $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$, $z \frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ and $z^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial z}$. They form a Lie algebra isomorphic to $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$. You can see this by direct computation, but a better method is to notice that they are the infinitesimal version of the $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$ action on $\mathbb{CP}^1$. This, the orbit structure is described by one parameter subgroups of $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$ and should come down to some computations with Jordan form.

**Structure 2** As in your previous question, identify $TS^2$ with $\{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{C}^3 : x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1 \}$. This can't be the same as structure $1$ because $\mathbb{CP}^1$ doesn't embed holomorphically into $\mathbb{C}^3$, so there is no place for the zero section to land. Let's call this complex manifold $X$.

There is a holomorphic map $X \to \mathbb{CP}^1$, sending $(x,y,z)$ to whichever of $(x+iy:1-z)$ and $(1+z:x-iy)$ is well defined. (If both are well defined then the equation $(x+iy)(x-iy) = (1+z)(1-z)$ shows they are equal.) This is an affine bundle, meaning that the fibers are $\mathbb{C}$'s and the transition maps are in $\mathbb{C}^{\times} \ltimes \mathbb{C}$. But it doesn't have any sections at all, since $\mathbb{CP}^1$ doesn't embed in $\mathbb{C}^3$, so it isn't a line bundle.

Moreover, you can turn an affine bundle into a line bundle by applying the quotient map $\mathbb{C}^{\times} \ltimes \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}^{\times}$ to the transition functions. (The resulting line bundle is diffeomorphic to the original affine bundle, since all affine bundles have sections in the smooth category.) But I get that the result is $\mathcal{O}(-2) \cong T^{\ast} S^2$, not $T S^2$. Of course, those are the same as smooth manifolds, but they are different as holomorphic manifolds. (As symplectic manifolds, I don't know.)

Comment: what is the explicit vector  space  structure on each fiber when you define $[x+yi,1-z]? what is the trivializations ?

Comment: It was interesting for me that the formula which you mentioned is similar to representation of  all projections in $M_{2}(\mathbb{C})$ in the  matrix form $$\begin{pmatrix} 1-z&x+yi\\x-yi&1+z\end{pmatrix}$$ $x,y,z$ are real with $x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}=1$.

Answer (score 1):

$TS^2\to S^2$ has Euler class $2$; ergo, the line bundle in question is $\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb P^1}(2)$. It's holomorphic sections form a vector space of dimension $3$; they can be thought of as degree $\le2$ polynomials on $\Bbb C$.

**Added in proof:** All this is independent of the holomorphic structure on $TS^2$ assuming that there is a fibration $TS^2\to S^2$. Indeed, over $\Bbb P^1$, a line bundle is determined by its $\text{degree}=c_1=e$ (Euler class), and the latter is the self-intersection of the zero section, which, in turn, is the generator of $H_2(TS^2)=\Bbb Z$. So, everything is in the topology of the **oriented** manifold $TS^2$.

Comment: thanks  for the  answer. could  you please more explain, with some  references  please? what is  "ergo"?  what is the algebraic or holomorphic  projecting  map $g$? Are  you considering the  first question?

Comment: "ergo" is the Latin for "hence". No, I'm not considering the first question, since you are using $q$ and $p$, implying that the two are unrelated. However, **assuming** that you **do** have a fibration and that $S^2\subset TS^2$ is its zero section, the Eiler class (${}=c_1$ in this dimension) is merely the self-intersection $[S^2]^2$, so it's independent of the structures involved. (In fact, you don't even need to assume that $S^2$ is the zero section, as it's the generator of $H_2(TS^2)$ and the square of this class depends on nothing but the orientation.)

Comment: Sorry, concerning your other questions: I take for the projection just the natural projection, but this is irrelevant (see above). For characteristic classes, the keywords are "obstruction theory"; for the dimension, the name would be Riemann--Roch theorem, even though this is an overkill. (So I'm not including this into the answer :)

Comment: thank you very much for your  attention on the  question.I  would  appreciate if  you include  some  elementary references.:)

Comment: I'm not good at that. As I said, the topological part is the obstruction theory (any textbook in algebraic topology that covers this subject): in dimension $\dim_{\Bbb R}=2\dim_{\Bbb C}=2$, both $c_1$ and $e$ are obstructions to the same thing, viz. existence of a section; hence, they are equal. I do not have a formal education in algebraic geometry; everything about $\Bbb P^1$ is **very** classical but, from the modern point of view, it's Hodge theory ($h^1=\frac12b_1=0$, hence holomorphic classification is the same as topological for line bundles) plus Riemann--Roch for the dimension.

Comment: For the dimension, you can also use common sense: a bundle is determined by its degree $d$, hence sections are merely polynomials of degree $\le d$. All this is covered (I hope) in Hirzebruch's "Topological methods in algebraic geometry", but I'm sure that algebraic geometers will name lots of much more elementary texts about $\Bbb P^1$.