# Manifold whose symplectic structure of the cotangent bundle is intrinsically different from any symplectic structure arising from $\mathbb{C}^n$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry

Inspired by this question [Symplectic structure of  $TS^{n-1}$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/150344/symplectic-structure-of-tangent-bundle-of-mathbbsn-1) we  ask:

> What is  an example of  a  manifold  $M$ whose cotangent bundle   $T^*M$ is  an Stein manifold but the canonical symplectic structure of $T^*M$ is  equivalent to no symplectic structure imposed on $T^*M$ via a holomorphic embedding in some $\mathbb{C}^n$? In the other word: we search for a manifold $M$ such that $T^*M$ is a  holomorphic submanifold of some $\mathbb{C}^n$  so it admits some  symplectic structures  inherited frm $\mathbb{C}^n$ but non of this structures obtained in this way is symplectomorphism to the canonical structure of the cotangent bundle $T^* M$.

**Note;**  It seems that  the assumption "The  cotangent  bundle is  an  Stein manifold" is  redundant". Namely it seems that  every  cotangent bundle is  an Stein  manifold. Since The  whole  cotangent  bundle is  diffeomorphic  to the disc bundle $T^*_{r}M$, the  disc  bundle of  radius $r$. In the  following  conversation one observe that there exist an  Stein structure on the  disc  bundle.  [Please see the  link  bellow:  How does one complexify a real $n$-dimensional Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2861487/how-does-one-complexify-a-real-n-dimensional-riemannian-manifold-m-g/4535269#4535269)

**A  Confession:** I  confess I did not  read the details of the paper of   Bruhat-Whitney and the paper of  Lempert.  But I guess that their constructions leads us to a  negative  answer to this post.

Comment: Since this is two questions, it seems like it might be worth two separate posts, unless you expect the answers for some reason to inform one another.  (Note, for example, that you cannot two answers.)

Comment: @LSpice  Thank you for your  suggestion.  I revised the question